# Can't find System.Windows.GridLength in ..Net5.0

Tags: c#, .net-5

I'm having trouble converting an application from .NetFramework to .Net5.0. For example, I have a variable of type System.Windiws.GridLength correctly set in Properties.Settings.Default that I can no longer refer to in Net5.0 because it is nowhere to be found (I get the error "System.Windows.GridLength type is not defined" by inserting the type name in the appropriate field in the type selection window shown by choosing the 'Browse' item from the pop-up menu in the 'Type' column of the Settings window). What i am missing?

**** EDIT ************

My project's .csproj as requested:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <PropertyGroup>
   <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
   <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
   <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
   <StartupObject>Stats4Betting_NetCore.App</StartupObject>
   <ApplicationIcon>Resources\soccer_boom_alt.ico</ApplicationIcon>
   <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64;x86</Platforms>
</PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    ....
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: What kind of project is this? (I'd expect it to be available, but only for desktop-targeted apps.)

Comment: GridLength is part of WPF -- on .NET Framework you needed to reference `PresentationFramework.dll`, and on .NET Core you need to make sure you're targetting a Windows (e.g. a TargetFramework of `net5.0-windows`) and also have `<UseWPF>true</UseWPF>`. If you're not writing a WPF app, you probably don't want to do this (you'll be limited to Windows for example), so you should probably pick a better data type

Comment: `System.Windows.*` are typically WPF types. In .NET 5.0 and above it should be available if you target Windows  (net5.0-windows)

Comment: Ok, my project target is a net5.0 wpf (not netcore5 as i thought before!). I'm new to this framework, but if its some new versione of .netframework, gridlength type should be already part of my project by default, isn't it?

Comment: Please post your .csproj

Comment: That csproj looks fine: `GridLength` should be available. Are you sure it's not just a problem with the settings editor UI?

Comment: I had to add both the Properties folder and the Settings.settings file inside it to mimic the structure of the original .NetFramework project, but other than that it's all the same, so I don't understand what could be causing the error I'm getting in variable setting. Previously, given the name to the new item, I selected its type by going to Type-> Browse (from the popup menu) and, manually entering the name of the type in the appropriate field, I pressed enter and I was finished.